# QR Code Generator with number picker and date picker in android

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I am new to android studio, I am doing a qr code project which i have used date picker and number picker and i have tried to write code and it came out with different result which not i expected.
I have seen most of the qr code generator tutorial or example, it used zxing library and edittext for the qr code generator, so I have tried with myself coding it with date picker and nubmer picker.
How Can I make it the result which i expected? result like this: 1234567<-id 1019<-time 15<-minutes

MyCode java class:

```
public class Visitor extends Activity {

    DatePicker timeDp;
    NumberPicker minNp;
    private String[] minutesArray;
    Button createBtn;
    ImageView qrcodeIv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qrcode);
        minNp = findViewById(R.id.npMin);
        minNp.setMaxValue(5);
        minNp.setMinValue(0);
        minutesArray = new String[] {"15","30","45","60","75","90"};
        minNp.setDisplayedValues(minutesArray);
        qrcodeIv = findViewById(R.id.ivQrcode);
        createBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);

        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
        int value = minNp.getValue();
        parameters.put("mins", Integer.toString(value));

        createBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try {
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(String.valueOf(minNp), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,400,400);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                qrcodeIv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(minNp.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

qr code design page:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Select Time"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/tp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Select Minutes"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/npMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivQrcode"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
```

I had my qr code result show like this: **android.widget.NumberPicker{ba98302 VFED..... ........ 452,914-628,1409 #7f08013f app:id/npMin}**.

I had import everything which I needed in android studio, but the result didn't show what I want.

My expected result should be like this:  1234567 1019 15
^     ^    ^
id  time  minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

`BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(String.valueOf(minNp), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,400,400);`

by calling `String.valueOf(minNp)` you create a `String` that describes the instance of `NumberPicker`. Basically this is just another way of calling the `toString()` method of `minNp`.

You need to call `minNp.getValue()` which will return the value as an `int`. This value should be the index in the `minutesArray`.

The code would look like this:

`BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(minutesArray[minNp.getValue()], BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,400,400);`

Comment: but it doesn't match the value which i have for **minutesArray** String

Comment: Your, right. I edited my answer. I hope it makes sense now.